# get description of variable on tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I set on context.xml some variable with some description.

```
<Environment
name="var"
description="description"
type="java.lang.String"
/>
```

I read it with:

```
variable = (String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/var");
```

How can I get the value description of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Description* attribute is there only for documentation purposes.

You should use `value` attribute to assign a value to the environment variable:

```
 <Context>
    <Environment name="yourVariable" 
                 value="yourValue" 
                 type="java.lang.String" 
                 description="this assigns yourValue to yourVariable" /> 
 </Context>
```

This way, when you do

```
String variable = (String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/yourVariable");
```

`variable` will contain string "yourValue".